# Error runnning VB script - WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: vbscript

We are trying to run VB script but getting below error.

C:\Windows\system32>cscript /NoLogo "<C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_ad_fsmo.vbs>" DCName "PDC"
<C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_ad_fsmo.vbs(30>, 2) WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.

Script taken from below link
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows-NRPE/check_ad_fsmo-2Evbs/details

Kindly advice how to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error on line 30, it would appear netdom.exe is not installed on your system or the path in the script is not correct.

```
strCommand = "C:\progra~1\suppor~1\netdom.exe query /domain:" & domain & " fsmo"
```

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: Its an answer in the form of a question ;-) I have edited it to be more clear.